# Trigger click event from directive using AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have HTML template which shows left menu bar as shown below:

```
<li>
  <a href="!#" class="menu-dropdown">
    <i class="menu-icon fa fa-cog"></i>
    <span class="menu-text">GST Returns</span>
    <i class="menu-expand"></i>
  </a>
  <ul class="submenu">
    <li>
      <a>
        <span class="menu-text">GSTR-1</span>
      </a>
      <ul class="submenu" id="toggleOpen1" ng-click="ClickToggle(1)">
        <li>
          <a href="xxx">
            <span class="menu-text">Save</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="xxx">
            <span class="menu-text">File</span>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>
        <span class="menu-text">GSTR-2A</span>
      </a>
      <ul class="submenu" id="toggleOpen2" ng-click="ClickToggle(2)">
        <li>
          <a href="xxxx">
            <span class="menu-text">Download</span>
          </a>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>
        <span class="menu-text">GSTR-2</span>
      </a>

      <ul class="submenu" id="toggleOpen3" ng-click="ClickToggle(3)">
        <li>
          <a>
            <span class="menu-text">Save</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a>
            <span class="menu-text">File</span>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

I want to click trigger of the function `ClickToggle(1)`. My directive looks like this:

```
app.directive('leftBar', [function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'templates/directives/new-left-bar.html',
  };
}]);
```

Here in index HTML I'm loading my directive:

```
<div class="page-sidebar" 
     data-toggle="tooltip" 
     data-original-title="Toggle Left Bar" 
     id="sidebar">
  <left-bar></left-bar>
</div>
```

So I want to fire click event from my `sub-menu` through my directive.

Comment: Why do you mix `onclick` and `ng-click`?

Comment: use scope in link or controller in your directive

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. That code should be… **Minimal** – Use as little code as possible that still produces the same problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily do it with a `link` function inside your directive configuration like in this **[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/n3f8oj7z/)**. Your controller `$scope` will be parsed into the link function in your directive. All controller based `$scope` objects can be accessed inside the directive link function. You may going to checkout all the good stuff by using AngularJS directive by reading the [directives documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).

#### Controller example:

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.ClickToggle = function (id) {
      console.log(id);
    }
});
```

#### Directive Template

```
<div class="page-sidebar" 
     data-toggle="tooltip" 
     data-original-title="Toggle Left Bar" 
     id="sidebar">
  <left-bar ng-click="clickMe()"></left-bar>
</div>
```

#### Directive Code:

```
app.directive('leftBar', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'templates/directives/new-left-bar.html',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.clickMe = function() {
        scope.ClickToggle(1);
      };
    }
  }
});
```